# How can I return value from onResponse of Volley?

Tags: android, parsing, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I want to save values from Response on user class variables.
Unfortunately, I cannot.

Help me please.

This is the code JSONObjectRequest

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    jsonURLFull, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
          Log.d(ActivityLogin.class.getSimpleName(), response.toString());

          try {
              User userClass = new User();

              JSONObject jsonUser = response.getJSONObject("user");
              userClass.id = jsonUser.getInt("id");
              userClass.name = jsonUser.getString("email");
              userClass.email = jsonUser.getString("email");

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          hidepDialog();
      }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          VolleyLog.d(ActivityLogin.class.getSimpleName(), "Error: " + error.getMessage());
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          hidepDialog();
      }
  });
  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

This is the User class:

```
public class User {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String email;

}
```

This is the JSON of the API:

```
{"user":{"id":12,"name":"test_name","email":"test@email.com",}}
```

Comment: please apply setter getter in user class because if you are not making it.It would be garbage collected.

Comment: Use Setter Getter and then pass your User class object "userClass", where  
you want to use these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points for you :

1.you parse `email` to `name` attribude.

```
  userClass.name = jsonUser.getString("name");
```

2.your json data is wrong due to the last `','`

```
{"user":{"id":12,"name":"test_name","email":"test@email.com"}}
```